# How to access the bin directory in Tableau 2020.2 using python and automate data connection update using tableau utility command line

Tags: python, windows, cmd, tableau-api

I want to write a python script and run it in command line. The script is supposed to go to bin directory in tableau 2020.2 folder and run a command like this

```
tableau refreshextract --server "Tableau server" --username soroush --password "password" --site "site id" --project "project name" --datasource "DS name" --original-file "file address"
```

and updates the data source name based on a list of name that is provided by user.

I tried to use

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

def main():
  os.chdir("C:\Program Files\Tableau\Tableau 2020.2\bin")
  print(lst)       
      
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

to go to the directory and run the tableau utility command. And it gives this error

```
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'C:\\Program Files\\Tableau\\Tableau 2020.2\x08in'
```

. So I guess there is something about the fact that bin has binary files in it and Windows does not let python have access to it.

I appreciate if someone points me to the right direction.

I know this question may sound silly to some of you but I do not have the required background to know about these stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The escape character '\' needs to be escaped.

```
os.chdir("C:\\Program Files\\Tableau\\Tableau 2020.2\\bin")
```

Alternatively, a raw string can be used.

```
os.chdir(r"C:\Program Files\Tableau\Tableau 2020.2\bin")
```

Comment: Thanks. It solved my problem. Now I can connect to the bin directory.